# MapReduce -Is there way to overwrite a output directory through CustomOutputFormat class?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I would like to overwrite a output directory in mapreduce but it throws an exception as "FileAlreadyExists". Is there way to overwrite a output directory by creating custom output class?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, is check if the output directory exists. if it does delete it all it's contents.

To do it, use the `[FileSystem][1]` class in your driver class.

```
    Path outputPath = new Path("/user/foor/jobOutput");
    Job job = new Job();


    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(outputPath.toUri(),job.getConfiguration());
    fs.delete(outputPath, true);


    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
```

Comment: I just override the method checkoutputspec in the class FileOutputFormat by this way:  @Override
   public void checkOutputSpecs(JobContext job)
   throws FileAlreadyExistsException,
          IOException {

        // bypass the output directory check.

    }

Comment: After override that method, I can able to overwrite in the existing output folder.

Comment: @Vignesh how will that work when you have files with not be overwritten? eg. the 2nd run does not work, but you will have the _SUCESS file from the previous run. This to not mention other problems...

Comment: I can able to overwrite in the input path, as you said it has part files and success files. I just wants to delete those when I run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Output file from MapReduce will be in HDFS. HDFS runs on the concept of write once and read many times. So you cannot overwrite a output directory. You have to delete it and write it again through MapReduce

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Shravanya. I override the method checkoutputspec in FileOutputFormat class.

Comment: Even if you override that method, you cannot overwrite it directly. however while you are overriding, you can add a functionality to delete the existing output file if it exists and write it again.